# How to identify if a plugin uses Scribd?

Tags: plugins, socialengine, scribd

I am installing new plugins for Social Engine since the current plugin running on Scribd which is shutting down in the near future. 
Is there anyway I can identify if my plugin using Scribd.
These are two option I am considering:
http://www.orangemantra.com/socialengine-event-document-plugin

http://www.socialengine.com/customize/se4/mod-page?mod_id=810

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out if the plugins are using Scribd, is to contact the vendor of the plugins and they'll help you with your question.